# How to use a license with JWrapper

Tags: jwrapper

So I have been working with the free version of JWrapper for some time now and have been quite pleased with the results; however, I have now purchased a license and would like to use it but I am unable to find the method with which to activate my JWrapper. I do not use the graphical interface version of JWrapper; rather I have created a xml installation file and pass that directly via commandline to JWrapper for building. Is there a special xml tag for specifying the license location? I was unable to find this information on JWrapper's homepage or support docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer from the support team. In order to use the license without using the JWrapperApp gui to build your application you will simply have to have the jwlicense.txt file in the same directory as your jwrapper.jar

Answer (score 0):

After some tests it appears that the jwlicence.txt file must be in the current directory. So the best is to have all the files (jwrapper jar, jwrapper.xml and jwlicence.txt) in the same folder and run the compiler from that folder.